# did static fry my uv5r?

Tags: baofeng, transmitter, uv-5r

I was hit with a big arc of static from a metal door frame.

I was a little over a foot away. It stung pretty good, then my coworker told me I was transmitting.

My baofeng uv5r will not stop transmitting unless I turn it off. I turn it on and as soon as it boots it starts transmitting again.

All the buttons just make tones like a phone, but I can't get into menu or change channels or anything.

After a little while she says *transmit overtime* and cuts out, but I still can't unlock or access the menu.

I tried downloading with chirp but even that won't work. Vox is not on, and if I press the PTT button I can feel it click.

I tried a different battery too. De-soldering the PTT button doesn't solve the issue, either.

Comment: de-soldering the ptt button from the pcb does not fix the issue

Comment: i think its possible whatever failed may have already been on the decline, i have 4 uv5r radios. i was using a new headset last week and the ptt button on the headset quit working on day 2. i assumed it was the headset and just used the ptt button on the radio. today i tested the headset ptt button and it works  on my other radio.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds very much to me as if something connected to the PTT (the electronics that the physical switch activates) was damaged.  With what a BaoFeng costs, unless you're just curious, it's not worth putting much time into troubleshooting.  As a bonus, the battery you have appears to be okay, so you'll have a spare battery (which can be charged off the radio; it plugs into the desk charger just like the radio does).